# Is it possible to use cURL to grab files via SSH?

Tags: php, curl, ssh

I've looked into the SSH2 module for PHP, but it would require a PHP recompile on a server which is very bloated.  It's far more of a risk than we'd like to take on right now.

Is it possible for me to use cURL to grab a few files over SSH?  I've done some Googling and found a few sources but nothing 100% clear on whether this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain about cURL, but if you don't want to recompile but the server has ssh clients installed already, you can make a system call to `scp`. It will work best, of course, if you have SSH keys in place between the local and remote hosts.

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/scp -i private_key_identity user@host:/path/to/remote/file /local/path");
```

Answer (score 1):

CURL won't work unfortunately. You can, as @Michael suggested, use scp, or if you need to copy the files on a regular basis, I would suggest `rsync` as it will only transfer the differences between the file content.

```
exec('/usr/bin/rsync -az user@remotehost:/path/to/directory/* /path/to/local/directory/');
```

Flag`-a` will use archive mode, see the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for more details. The `-z` flag will compress the transfer.

`rsync` will also transfer via `SSH`, so make sure you have the privat/public keys set up correctly.