# How to setup curl using SSH tunner

Tags: php, curl, ssh

i have ssh , and i want to use for cURL.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$server = '123.456.789.012';
$port = 22;
$user = 'root';
$pass = '123456';
$connection = ssh2_connect($ip, $port, $methods, $callbacks);
if (!$connection) die('Connection failed');
$auth = ssh2_auth_password ($connection, $user, $pass);
$tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, '127.0.0.1', 1080);
if(!$tunnel) die('error');

$url = 'http://dynupdate.no-ip.com/ip.php';
$proxy = '127.0.0.1:1080';
//$proxyauth = 'user:password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "ok ".$curl_scraped_page;
?>
```

http://pastebin.com/8mtYwX2R

Im using CentOS os

Who can help me

Comment: This really isn't a code question.  I would suggest moving it to:http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885475/is-it-possible-to-use-curl-to-grab-files-via-ssh

Comment: i cant using [code] tag. have an error

Answer (score 0):

Curl is primarily used for web related query, I am not sure curl will get back with any response if you use it for ssh. I am seeing your code and seems you are not doing anything just trying to login through ssh and returning back. However if you want to run some command after ssh login you can use ssh command for that. If you want to copy some file you can also use scp. So let me know exactly what you are trying to achieve when you are SSHing via curl.

Answer (score 0):

libssh2 is a client. For `ssh2_tunnel` to behave the way your code is expecting it to it'd have to start up a server on 127.0.0.1::1080. And not just any server but a SOCKS5 server.

Here's how ssh2_tunnel is used:

```
$tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, '127.0.0.1', 1080);
fputs($tunnel, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.domain.tld\r\n\r\n");
while (true) {
    echo fgets($tunnel, 1024);
}
```